# Short circuiting a SQL statement conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, logical-operators

This is an excerpt from a large SQL statement that I'm trying to optimize.

```
<removed>
```

see here: [Query with execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryT2Slep9)

It runs on SQL Server 2017 and does the following things:

1. process the base tables and calculate intermediate queries (sql)
2. run (exec) the intermediate sql to calculate intermediate results
3. use intermediate results and base tables to get final results

I have been trying to optimize and did the following

- added indices with include columns
- replaced #temp tables with table variables
- removed cursor and other loops
- replaced all `SELECT *` with `SELECT <columns>`
- tried short circuiting some of the conditions
- replaced two or more occurrences of a sub query with the result set.

However, I'm out of tricks here.

Initially I pasted a part of the query but that wsn't really helpful so  with permission I have pasted the query with some minor changes of names.

My question is optimization of the script. Can there be any more measures taken to reduce it further?

Comment: Unlike programming languages such as Java and C#, SQL does not use any short-circuiting rules.  This means here that the SQL Server engine may choose to evaluate _any_ of the ANDed conditions in your `WHERE` clause first, and the others in any order, if it deems it be beneficial for the execution plan.

Comment: I was trying to solve it using logic algebra. if the current condition is X OR (!X AND Y) then it seems equivalent to X OR Y as both yield the same result. I'm not sure if that effects the performance in SQL Server

Comment: Unless you actually have a performance issue I wouldn't attempt to optimise it.

Comment: there are 8 such conditions. I have written only one. currently the execution plan shows that only this SQL statement (whose where clause i have here) takes 91% time in SP. so yes there is performance issue.

Comment: Magnitude makes a difference. Is it 91% of 1ms, so not worth worrying about, or 91% of 60s? You haven't shown us a query plan, so I'm only guessing, but consider that execution planner may be choosing to execute this subquery on an RBAR (Row By Agonizing Row) basis when it may be better to restructure it as a left join over a query that's grouping by B.MP_CODE and B.SEQ_ID to use as join conditions. Is there any way to remove the `'%SOMETHING%'` conditions because they basically neuter any indexes on those columns - even `'SOMETHING%'` would be an improvement.

Comment: Have a read through Aaron Bertrand's article, [One way to get an index seek for a leading %wildcard](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/02/sql-indexes/seek-leading-wildcard-sql-server).

Comment: For performance questions, we need to see at a minimum: the full query, the relevant tables *and indexes*, and please share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com. The question is not answerable without this info.

Comment: @Charlieface please check the updated question with link to Pastebin

Comment: Looks like you can combine the last two subqueries and just finish them off with `AND A.STATUS = CASE WHEN ps.POP_BASE_SCHEME = 1 THEN 'I' ELSE 'E' END` and remove the outer filter on `ISNULL(ps.POP_BASE_SCHEME, 0)`. Like I said, we need tables and indexes also, and the query plan is a must, please share via the link above

Comment: Do you mean query execution plan? well how can get and paste it bcoz its all graphical, zooming out makes it hardly readable

Comment: That's why I said you should use https://pastetheplan.com which is made for this. You can share a link in your post. Right click the graphical plan and click View XML

Comment: added the query plan, see the updated question